# ArcPy featureclasstoshapefile_conversion- Duplicating files

Tags: arcpy

Working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1

I have a simple Python script to export all feature classes in a specific feature data set to a shapefile. It works, but it appears to duplicate the feature classes while exporting.

For example for 1 FC it produces 27 shapefiles of the same data and appends "_XX" after the name (XX is the number of duplicates)

My code is below... No idea why this is occurring, and it's 27 duplicates every time.

```
import arcpy


arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\Database.sde\path_to_Feature_dataset"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
rawOut = r"Y:\output folder path"

inFeatures = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in inFeatures:
    print "Exporting " + str(feature)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(inFeatures, rawOut)
    print str(feature) + " Export complete! \n"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `inFeatures` variable in the loop. I guess you have 27 featureclass and you copy all featureclasses in every loop, so, `FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion` tool duplicates them 27 times.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\Database.sde\path_to_Feature_dataset"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
rawOut = r"Y:\output folder path"

inFeatures = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for feature in inFeatures:
    print "Exporting " + str(feature)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(feature, # not inFeatures
                                             rawOut)
    print str(feature) + " Export complete! \n"
```

Comment: wow, I will go lock myself in a closet now.... thanks for the help lol